# Local variable undefined in respond_to json block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have the following block of code that renders a form.  The form will have it's "action" set depending on the format requested.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render "new", :locals => {:format => "html"} }
  format.json do
    render 'new.html', {
      :locals       => {:format => "json"},
      :content_type => 'text/html',
      :layout       => false
    } 
  end
end
```

The problem is with `:locals => {:format => "json"}`.
The `format.html` block works fine, but the form rendered by `format.json` has the `@format` variable defined but blank.  Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables are not set as instance variables when passed to render with the `locals` option. The format variable should be available as just that, a local variable (`format vs @format`)

The reason you're seeing @format as being defined is because that is how Ruby works. When instance variables are accessed before they are assigned to a value, they will return nil:

```
@format # => nil
@format = 'value'
@format # => 'value'
```